# Curly brackets below a word in an equation

Tags: equations

How to write this equation in latex?

I wrote this code but not getting it.

[image]

```
E_{t-2}P_t=\frac{1}{2}(E_{t-2}m_t+\underbrace{E_{t-2}v_t}_\textrm{=0}-\underbrace{E_{t-2}u_t}_\textrm{=0}+(\frac{(1-\zeta )}{2})(\underbrace{E_{t-2}E_{t-1}P_t}_\textrm{=E_{t-2}}+\underbrace{E_{t-2}E_{t-2}P_t}_\textrm{=E_{t-2}})+(\frac{\zeta }{2})(E_{t-2}P_{t-1}+E_{t-2}P_{t-2})
```

Comment: Please add some `\usepackage`s to make your code compilable.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What kind of '\usepackage' should I use?

Comment: Anyway you already got an answer, but this is my note for your future questions: if you are using Mathjax, do not ask it here as Mathjax is off topic on this site. Sometimes we need a compilable code to reproduce the issue, and without it we can hardly do anything.

Comment: Hey, no offence, but I'm using LaTex only.

Comment: I believe JouleV is asking for an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?noredirect=1&lq=1). The point is if I copy and paste the code you have written into a blank `.tex` file and try to compile it, it won't work. So then I have to do the job of adding a template, with a `\documentclass` and perhaps `\usepackage{amsmath}` and so on, `\begin{document}` etc. and you could have saved me that tiny chore. It's polite and helps us to help you.

Comment: But more importantly, sometimes, if *I* try to add my own preamble, I might get it wrong. Doesn't really seem to apply here, but there are many questions where people might be using packages that I haven't got in my standard template, so I then have to work out which package provides the command that's giving me an error. Or the solution that I write, not knowing about the packages you are using, may not work for you because you're using some package `xyz` that clashes, you see? So it's nice to provide a minimal document that I can just plug in and play with

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're almost there. Instead of

```
\underbrace{E_{t-2}v_t}_\textrm{=0}
```

type

```
\underbrace{E_{t-2}v_t}_{=0}
```

etc

---

I would also introduce some line breaks in the long equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\E_{t-2}P_t=
\frac{1}{2}\Bigl(\E_{t-2}m_t
+\underbrace{\E_{t-2}v_t}_{=0}
-\underbrace{\E_{t-2}u_t}_{=0}\Bigr) \\
+\frac{(1-\zeta )}{2}\Bigl(
\underbrace{\E_{t-2}\E_{t-1}P_t}_{=\E_{t-2}}+
\underbrace{\E_{t-2}\E_{t-2}P_t}_{=\E_{t-2}}\Bigr) \\
+\frac{\zeta }{2}\Bigl(\E_{t-2}P_{t-1}+\E_{t-2}P_{t-2}\Bigr)
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/) to generate LaTeX code for any mathematical equation by simply taking a screenshot of the equation. It will save you tons of time in future like it did for me after I discovered it!

[image: Mathpix demo]

Comment: It is pretty cool, but I never recommend automated generators for LaTeX. They may give nice results, but never good results.

Comment: I totally agree. I too never rely completely on automated generators, but I do find it much easier to tweak the codes rather than building it up from the scratch. Also, these codes help you learn LaTeX as well!

Comment: You know, I have to upvote your answer for the last sentence of your comment

Comment: Thanks! I can't thank the developers of this software enough for helping me prepare a report with too many equations in it with significantly lesser efforts as well as enriching my LaTeX vocabulary.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this posting does *not* address the OP's question. Why? You copied-and-pasted a screenshot from my answer -- which, ahem, is already known to be based on valid LaTeX code -- and showed that the software can generate something that resembles decent, though not solid, LaTeX code. (Why "not solid"? Well, for one, note the use of `$$` to start and stop an unnumbered displayed equation -- definitely not good practice for a LaTeX document.) It would be more impressive if you demonstrated that working with the OP's screenshot led to a satisfactory chunk of LaTeX code.

Comment: @Mico, if you read the previous comments in this thread, you will realize that I never claimed that this software gives perfect results. What I said was that the code that this software produces can be used as a starting point and you can build upon that. Also, I took the screenshot from your answer because I wanted to show that the code that Mathpix generates is pretty similar to what you have come up with. Finally, when you take a screenshot, the software doesn't know how that equation was generated, it simply uses optical character recognition to come up with the code.